# Cannot call method 'match' of undefined handlebar issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, handlebars.js

I have my template with handlebar and is working the most quantity of time but sometimes give me this error Cannot call method 'match' of undefined. This is my code

view

```
      <div id="template"></div>
            <script id="template-script" type="text/x-handlebars-template">  
                {{#measures_list}}      
                    <div class="col-lg-7  col-lg-offset-1">                     
                            <p class="indicator-title gray-bottom-border">{{name}}</br></p>
                            <div>
                                <p><span class="font30px">{{total}} </span> Total {{name}}<br><span class="green-text">{{increase}}%</span> from last <span class="metric_time"></span></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="graph-header">
                                <h3>{{this_interval}} </h3><p>New {{name}}</p>
                                <p class="percentage-graph green-text">{{percentage}}%<p>
                            </div>                      
                        <div id={{graph_id}} class="graph"></div>

                    </div>
                {{/measures_list}} 
            </script>
```

js

```
   var source=$("#template-script").html();
   var template=Handlebars.compile(source);
   $('#template').empty().append(template(template_data));
   console.log('source'+source+'template'+template)
```

I use the console.log to see the error, so many times work perfectly but in somme case source is undefined, the page appears many times, for example I click on a button and appears after I close the page and click on the button again and do that many times, after many times or after the first time give me the error: **Cannot call method 'match' of undefined**

Any help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put all between script tags  in my js like a variable and called instead of source, my fix is beacuse sometimes cant find **source** but **source** is there, so I change to my js and is working.

Answer (score 0):

```
var source=$("#template-script").html() || '';
```

Comment: if (!source) console.log("HEY! YOU'RE PASSING IN AN EMPTY VARIABLE HERE!!")